# Number with comma delimiter

Tags: javascript, php, delimiter

I'm using in Zend framework and Jquery.

How can I add a comma delimiter to my numbers which are in PHP? I need also another
example for jquery comma delimiter.

example:
19282.10 -----> 19,282.10

Answer (score 4):

PHP: [`number_format`](http://php.net/number-format)

JavaScript: [`number_format` by PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format('19282.10', 2); // 19,282.10
```

Comment: Your example is incorrect - that code returns `19,282`. Pass `2` as the second parameter to add two decimal places.

Comment: @Kolink Good call. Even one more reason for +1'ing you